# Image addition expression that handles overflow and underflow as well

Tags: image-processing

Is there a mathematical expression that not only adds the corresponding pixels of an image but also handles the underflow and overflow of such an addition.E.g if we have a 8 bit image then if adding two corresponding pixel values return a sum greater than 255 then that output pixel value is set to 255 and same goes for underflow in which if the sum is less then 0 then the output value is set to 0.I need a single mathematical expression.Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
min(255, max(0, a+b))
```

This is a single mathematical expression.

Comment: Ok I am un checking this as an accepted answer because I just realized that when we call "min" and "max", they are in themselves using  if and else to do the job.I need an expression that doesn't involve any function calls or relational operators.It should only contain mathematical operators.Thanx

Comment: @Cheeta: `min` and `max` are perfectly valid mathematical operators.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element.